# How to make symbols in string move and bounce?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have the following task in university.
There are:

```
<div id='output'></div>
<button id='add-element'>Add</button>
```

It's need to fill *div* with '0' (100 symbols). After pressing button, first '0' in div (starting from the left side) should be replaced with '1' (amount of symbols in div must be always the same).
Every 500 ms '1' goes right and replaces next '0' since '1' gets to the end of the div. In this case '1' should change its direction and move backwards. Thus, '1' should move from one side to another changing position every 500 ms. 
Amount of '1' that can be added is limited by amount of symbols in *div*.
When one '1' meets another '1' they should change their directions of move to opposite.
Here is my wrong code:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('output');
let button = document.getElementById('add-element');
let zeros = [];
let ones = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  zeros[i] = '0';
}

div.textContent = zeros.join('');

function render() {
  let intervalMark = setInterval(move, 500);

  function move() {
    let buffer = zeros.slice();
    let onesKeys = Object.keys(ones);

    onesKeys.forEach(function(item) {
      item = +item;

      if (item > 98 || (item < 1 && !ones[item])) {
        ones[item] = !ones[item];
      }
      /*
      When you add more than one '1' problems appears. 
      I tried to make '1's bounce, but it even doesn't work when '1' follows another '1'.   
      */
      if (ones[item + 1] && (buffer[item + 1] != 0 && !ones[item + 1])) {
        ones[item] = !ones[item];
        ones[item + 1] = !ones[item + 1];
      } else {}

      if (ones[item]) {
        buffer[item] = '1';
        ones[item + 1] = ones[item];
      } else {
        buffer[item] = '1';
        ones[item - 1] = ones[item];
      };

      delete ones[item];
    });

    div.textContent = buffer.join('');
  }

}

button.onclick = function(event) {
  ones[0] = true;
  if (Object.keys(ones).length == 1) render();
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Courier' monospace;
}

div {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <button id="add-element">Add</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"When one '1' meets another '1' they should change their directions of move to opposite."_ Everything before that line somehow implies there is only one "1"? How / When do you add the second / nth "1" ?

Comment: I mean that another button click adds next '1'.

Comment: Haha, of course ... silly me. Of course you can click a button twice ... dough. I need to grab a coffee ...